# is it possible to update nested filed by uuid

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using update_by_query to update document,and i have a nested field named "`Myfield1`".There is a string field named "`id`" in "`Myfield1`".In my case,the mapping something like this:

```
"mapping":{
  "mytype":{
     "properties": {
       "Myfield1": {
         "type": "nested",
           "properties": {
             "id": {
               "type": "string"
             },
             "field2": {
               "type": "long"
             }
          }
        },
       "Title": {
         "type": "string"
       }
   }
   }
}
```

The field "`id`" in nested is unique generated by uuid.Then i want to update `field2` in the nested field `Myfield` by query with the following request.

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested":{
      "path":"Myfield1",
      "query":{"match":{"Myfield1.id":"uuid"}},
      "inner_hits":{"from":0,"size":1}
    }
  },
  "script":"for (field in ctx._source.Myfield1) {if(field.id=='uuid') {field.field2='new value'}}"
}
```

I know it work,but the efficiency of this `script` is too low.How can I write ”`script`“ to directly update the `field2` in inner_hits.Or maybe there are other efficient ways.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by `the efficiency of this script is too low`?

Comment: The script loop the nested field "Myfield1",then update.But i want know how to update the result 
 of  inner_hits directly.And field "id" in nested field "Myfield1" is unique,So I can accurately locate the data in the nested .

Comment: The `inner_hits` structure is just an artifact of the query which allows you to see only the nested documents that match the nested query, but it's not accessible in the script. Did you see any actual performance issue with your script?